# Fixing GIMP after LTS upgrade

Tags: 20.04, lts, gimp

I've upgraded from one LTS to the more recent one (20.04). As a result, if I try to load GIMP I get `gimp: fatal error: Segmentation fault`. But, if I run it as `sudo gimp` it works.

How do I go about diagnosing the problem (and fixing it)?

Update: It looks like `sudo gimp` was a fluke as this no longer works.

```
gimp --version

GNU Image Manipulation Program version 2.10.18
```

and

```
dpkg -l | grep -i gimp
ii  gimp                                                        2.10.18-1                                          amd64        GNU Image Manipulation Program
ii  gimp-data                                                   2.10.18-1                                          all          Data files for GIMP
ii  gimp-help-common                                            2.8.2-2ubuntu1                                     all          Data files for the GIMP documentation
ii  gimp-help-en                                                2.8.2-2ubuntu1                                     all          Documentation for the GIMP (English)
ii  libgimp2.0                                                  2.10.18-1                                          amd64        Libraries for the GNU Image Manipulation Program
ii  libgtk2-perl                                                2:1.24993-1ubuntu2                                 amd64        Perl interface to the 2.x series of the Gimp Toolkit library
```

Comment: Please add the output of `which gimp`; `gimp --version`; `snap list | grep -i gimp`; `flatpak list | grep -i gimp`; `dpkg -l | grep -i gimp` to the question.

Comment: I can't remember exactly how I fixed this. I identified a problem library uninstalled and reinstalled and that fixed it.